# Comparing Pareto fitting methods

Tags: r, curve-fitting, pareto-distribution

I am comparing different method of fitting Pareto distributed random numbers.
What seems very strange to me is that fitting a straight line in log-log scale has to be the worst numerical method and indeed it is, but when I superimpose the log-log histogram with that straight line they superimpose very good. The other fitting method superimpose very bad. How is it possible this paradox? I am doing some mistakes?

Here is my code in R for check:

```
 pareto.MLE <- function(X)
 {
    n <- length(X)
    m <- min(X)
    a <- n/sum(log(X)-log(m))
    curve(-(a+1)*x+log(a)+a*log(m),add=T,col='black')
    return( c(a) ) 
 }

 pareto.Alpha <- function (X)
 {  
    m <- min(X)
    mu <- mean(X)
    a <- mu/(mu-m)
    curve(-(a+1)*x+log(a)+a*log(m),add=T,col='green')
    return( c(a) )
  }


 pareto.median <- function (X)
 {  
    m <- min(X)
    med <- median(X)
    a <- log(2.)/log(med/m)
    curve(-(a+1)*x+log(a)+a*log(m),add=T,col='blue')
    return( c(a) )
  }

  pareto.fit <- function (X)

  {
    dd <-hist(X,plot=F)

    for(i in length(dd$counts):1)

 {
 if(dd$density[[i]]==0)
  {
  dd$density[[i]]=dd$density[[i+1]]
    }
}

   cc <-lm(log(dd$density)~log(dd$mids))
   curve(x*(coefficients(cc)[2])+(coefficients(cc)[1]),add=T,col='red')
   return( c(-1*(coefficients(cc)[2]+1)))  

   }

   library(PtProcess)
   alpha=1.
   hh1<-(matrix(rpareto(100,alpha,0.1),ncol=1))

   pp<-hist(hh1,plot=F)
   plot(log(pp$mids),(log(pp$density)))

   parameter.1<-pareto.MLE(hh1)
   parameter.a <- pareto.Alpha(hh1)
   parameter.m <- pareto.median(hh1)
   parameter.f <- pareto.fit(hh1)


   cat('Alpha: ',alpha,'\n')
   cat('MLE: ',parameter.1,'\n')
   cat('Mean: ',parameter.a,'\n')
   cat('Median: ',parameter.m,'\n')
   cat('Fit: ',parameter.f,'\n')
```

Comment: Seems to me that depends on the largeness of bins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Johnson, Kotz, and Balakrishnan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471584959) describe several estimators of the parameters of the Pareto distribution, including the linear regression one, method of moments, and MLE, and note that the MLE is the uniform minimum variance estimator of the two parameters jointly, and is unbiased.  On the other hand, a technique which is specifically designed to fit tails well will naturally tend to fit the tails better than a technique which fits the entire distribution weighted by likelihood (so to speak.)  What estimator is best for you depends upon your loss associated with misestimating the distribution.