# Why does the $\alpha$ parameter grow to $\infty$ in Pareto-distributed random numbers when changing the threshold?

Tags: pareto-distribution

I noted a strange fact. Let X be a set of Pareto distributed random number with $\alpha$ and $x_{\min}$ defined *a priori*.  Now, let $\alpha'$ be the estimated value of the shape and $x_{\min}'$ be a new threshold fixed *a posteriori*.

If $x_{\min}'\rightarrow \max(x)$ then $\alpha'\rightarrow +\infty$.

where $\max(x)$ is the max value in the sample.
I will try to explain me better.
Look at this code [Comparing Pareto fitting methods](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31352/comparing-pareto-fitting-methods) now imagine to add after the line

```
hh1 <- (matrix(rpareto(100,alpha,0.1),ncol=1))
```

(where 0.1 is $x_{\min}$)
this piece of code

```
hh1 <- subset(hh1,hh1 > xmin)
```

Here `xmin`${}=x_{\min}'$ namely the point where I start the fit or if you prefer a cut-off. 
Of course $x_{\min}'$ cannot be greater then $\max(x)$. Now imagine to put the code in a loop in order to see the behavior of $\alpha'$ while you increment the cut-off $x_{\min}'$.

What I would expect is when $x_{\min}'\rightarrow \max(x)$ then $\alpha'\rightarrow\alpha_0$ because they are independent. But this not happens and $\alpha'$ (the estimated) tend to infinity. Why do we have such a strange behavior during the estimation?  Well I understand the behavior in the MLE method, but the others?

The same happens with alpha-stable distributions when we try make a measure of the shape parameter in the tails.

Comment: what do you mean by "defined a priori" and "fixed a posteriori"?

Comment: defined a priori means: i choose the parameter and generate the random numbers. fixed a posteriori means: then i choose a threshold where to start fitting.

Comment: yes i have did it in a different "experiment", but what i am asking here is different. Why we have this behaviour even thought the two parameter are independents. Is a sort of conceptual experiment. I think it is important, because in general power law behaviour is present asymptotically in nature and we have to know where to starts fitting.

Comment: I agree with estimators, but what i would expects is sort of "plateu" in the behavior of $\alpha$, namely a behavior of this kind $\alpha\rightarrow\alpha_0$. I disagree with the last part of your comment. I can choose different Pareto distributions with the same $\alpha$ and different $x_{min}$ in this sense they are independent.

Comment: In this case (speaking of N parameters) means that the distribution has N degrees of freedom.

Comment: In what sense does "$x_{min}'\rightarrow +\infty$"? After all, necessarily $x_{min}$ is smaller than the smallest observed value! Are you perhaps discussing *truncation* of the distribution to values of $x_{min}$ or greater? Even so, $x_{min}'$ cannot exceed the largest observed value: truncation at larger values leaves one with no observations at all, whence no possibility of estimating $\alpha'$.

Comment: You right. $x_{min}'\rightarrow +\infty$ can be misled. Yes i am talking about truncation of the distribution.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail on your question.  What I would like to see is an explicit statement of the parameters: such as $(x_i|\alpha x_m)\sim Pareto(\alpha,x_m)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.  Then define $x_{min}$ - is it a statistic (i.e. function of the $x_i$) or a parameter?  Similarly, is $x_{min}^{'}$ a statistic or a parameter?  what about $\alpha^{'}$?

Comment: Emanuele, to add to @prob's query, I suspect the answer also depends on *how* one estimates $\alpha'$, so could you please indicate that, too?

Comment: $x_{min}$ is defined for creating pareto distributed sample of numbers. $x_{min}'$ is an arbitrary point where i truncate the sample and i start to fit. So $x_{min}' \ge x_{min}$ always: the behavior of $\alpha'$ is independent of the method i choose for fitting, i.e. MLE, mean (if $\alpha >1$), median and fitting a stright line in a log-log scale.

Comment: I think what @whuber is trying to get at is: (**1**) How does ${x'}_{\!\mathrm{min}}$ "converge to infinity? Is it as a function of the sample size? Or, in what (other) sense? (**2**) What means are you using to estimate $\alpha'$; for example, maximum likelihood? (Clearly, if you took as your estimate, say, $\hat\alpha' := 2$ by *ignoring the data altogether*, you would not have this problem! So, the estimation procedure *does* matter.)

Comment: you need to edit the question, not bury the details in a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x_{\min}^{'}\to\infty$ then we also have $x_i\to\infty$ and the type of convergence is "sure" convergence.  But note that just because two numbers both diverge does not mean that their limiting ratio is $1$.  This becomes clear once it is recognised that $x_{\min}$ is a scale parameter.  This is because we have:
$$\log\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{\min}}\right)\sim \operatorname{Expo}(\alpha)
$$
Expo(·) is the exponential distribution.  Now because the distribution is independent of $x_{\min}$ this is also the limiting distribution as $x_{\min}\to\infty$.

So the estimated value for $\alpha$ could be anything.  as the sample size increases, it will converge to the true value.

**Update**

In response to the revised question, the limit you are actually asking for is $x_{\min}^{'}\to x_{\max}$ not to infinity.  Now you ask why the estimate for $\alpha$ is infinite in this case.  Well the reason is that this limit corresponds to using a sample such that all of the values are equal $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_n=x_{\min}^{'}=x_{\max}$.  But in this case, the likelihood is exactly fitted by a dirac delta function.  The wikipedia page states that:
$$\lim_{\alpha\to\infty}f(x\mid x_{\min}^{'},\alpha)=\delta(x-x_{\min}^{'})$$
So the MLE procedure is not breaking down, but it is quite properly doing what it should: fitting the data as hard as it can within the class of distributions you give it.  You do get a warning though as the mle has infinite variance for all finite samples

Comment: I did not understand. why you say $log\left(\frac{x_i}{x_{min}}\right)\sim Exp(\alpha)$ ?

Comment: Probability, could you explain the sense in which you understand "$x_{min}'\rightarrow +\infty$"?  (See my related comment to the question itself.)

Comment: @whuber - I was treating $x_{min}^{'}$ as a fixed, known parameter of the Pareto distribution.  You can show that the sampling distribution of the MLE for $\alpha$ is invariant to both the sample minimum, and the lower bound parameter.  Only the values relative to the sample minimum matter, and this limit is arbitrary - a limit of a ratio of two divergent terms.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow this at all--must be Monday morning. :-) What is the relationship, then, between $x_{min}$ and $x_{min}'$ in your answer?

Comment: The pareto distribution is "invariant" to the distinction, as truncating a pareto sample to $x\geq x_{min}^{'}$ where $x\sim Pareto(\alpha,x_{min})$ just replaces $x_{min}\to x_{min}^{'}$.  Similar to memoryless property of exponential distribution

Comment: There are so many things that we don't know about the sampling process (yet), that it's hard to see how this gives a definitive answer. While it is true that $\newcommand{\xmin}{x_{\mathrm{min}}^{'}}\mathbb P(X > x \mid X > \xmin) = (\xmin / x)^{\alpha}$ for $x \geq \xmin$, the resulting sample size is *random* and we do not know what $\xmin \to \infty$ means. If it means that it is a *function* of the (latent) sample size $n$, then this response may provide some insight into the behavior of $\hat\alpha'$, or it may not relate *at all* to the behavior!)

Comment: (Imagine, e.g., as @whuber hints at, that $\xmin := \xmin(n)$ grows faster than the quantiles of the maximum of the (latent) sample, which is easy to compute.)

Comment: I think this means the question really needs to be editted.  I will edit my answer when that happens - if this takes too long, I'll remove my answer I think.  Note that if $\alpha$ is estimated by the wikipedia formula (as the comments indicate), then the only way $x_{min}^{'}$ can influence the estimate is through $n$.  I assumed that the *a posteriori* statement meant that we always have some sample, which basically means the estimate does not converge to anything unless $n\to 1$ or $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Fair enough. I completely agree that we need more info from the OP. But, I don't think that last comment is true, prob. For example, how do you "choose" $\xmin$ to "guarantee" you have a sample without looking at the data? And, if $\xmin$ is chosen by some data-driven procedure of the latent sample, then it can induce dependencies on the resultant truncated sample, in which case it will not "influence the estimate (only) through $n$".

Comment: What I interpretted "a posteriori" to mean is that you look at the data to choose $x_{min}^{'}$ - what else could be meant by "a posteriori"?  The estimate for $\alpha$ can be wriiten as $\hat{\alpha}=\alpha\frac{n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}[Y_{i}-Y_{(1)}]}$  where $Y_{i}\sim iid\;Expo(1)$ and $Y_{(1)}$ is the minimum of the $Y_{i}$  the only "data" based part of the estimator is $n$.

Comment: Unfortunately, the last sentence of your most recent comment is not true without knowing how $\xmin$ was arrived at.

Comment: yeah I just realised that now. $1$ should be replaced by $k$ which depends on $x_{min}^{'}$